# Use an operation of a class inside another class

Tags: c++, function, class

I have a class Maze with private members:

```
int i,j; // Position in an array bidimensional i rows, j columns in map
int x,y; // Position to draw the class in opengl, x coord and y coord in screen
```

So I need to translate from `i` (map,array) to `y` (screen) and `j` to `x`.
Inside class maze id also have an operation like:

```
int maze::getTransformMaptoScreenY(int i); would return the y value "translated" to screen size of the position i in the array
the same to j and get the x value in the screen

int maze::getTransformScreentoMapY(int i);
would return the i value "translated" from screen to map (array)
the same to j and get the Y value in the screen
```

so I'd need to use these operations inside the maze operation `draw`, something like

```
void Maze::draw()
{
 //ive to tranlate the walls, food, corridor from map to screen
 for i in rows
   for j in columns
         translate i,j to screen X,Y ( use getTransformMaptoScreenY and getTransformMaptoScreenX )
}
```

So I'd need to have a public function `getTransformMaptoScreenY` and perhaps a private function which would do the same operation and code.

Don’t know if its a better way to implement it or if I can call `getTransformMaptoScreenY` from one function....

Answer (score 1):

> So I'd need to have a public function getTransformMaptoScreenY and
>   perhaps a private function which would do the same operation and code.

Sounds like a perfect candidate for **NVI**-idiom:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not add display methods to you `Maze` class, but instead create a `MazeDisplayer` class that knows about screens and how to convert maze coordinates to screen coordinates. Consider the maze to be a model, and the MazeDisplayer provides a view on that model. Take a look at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-80-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for a little more info on what I'm referring to when I talk about a model and a view.

You might construct a MazeDisplayer by injecting a maze and a screen into it, such as

```
class MazeDisplayer {
public :
  MazeDisplayer(const Maze& maze, Screen& screen);
  ...
}
```

Comment: So id create a Maze class ( maze m; and m.draw() to draw it). So your proposal is to create a MazeDisplayer which i pass a maze m and the screen heigth and width. So i have to create a mazedisplayer md and then md.draw or can you be more specific please ? would be screen width and height a private members of MazeDisplayer ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I'd create a `Maze` class, then pass this to a `MazeDisplayer` class to draw it, and also pass a Screen class to the MazeDisplayer class (the Screen class knows the screen height and width). Then I'd call `md.draw`

Comment: Could be MazeDisplayer an inherit class from Maze ? Or totally different new class ? If i can i would edit the question with some pseudo-code or tests later today or tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: I would keep `MazeDisplayer` as a separate class. It isn't a type of `Maze`.